# facade always passing test never matter what return I expect

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, phpunit, laravel-facade, laravel-dusk

```
SkillAssessment::shouldReceive('addTwoNumbersAndAddName')
    ->with(3,5,'john')
    ->andReturn('thisstring is random and always passes anyway1341234123412343')->once();
```

A very basic mockup, expected return is:

`8 john`

so what I wanted to write is:

```
SkillAssessment::shouldReceive('addTwoNumbersAndAddName')
    ->with(3,5,'john')
    ->andReturn('8 john')->once();
```

it always passes, never matter if I write 8 join into the return or something else.

It fails though, as soon as I start changing say:addTwoNumbersAndAddName to something else, or `->with(4,10, 'john')` will fail

only the `->andReturn()` wont work

I am using laravel 5.4 and the command php artisan dusk

Comment: Can you please provide an example of it's failure.

Comment: its not about the failure, its about it passing without failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `andReturn` method *sets* what the test-double will return.

It will not check that a non-test-double would return that value on that method.

So it's perhaps just that you've confused that methods use.

Comment: so how can I test it returns the right value? where did you get your informations from?

Comment: I get the information from the Mockery documentation: http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/expectations.html#declaring-return-value-expectations - I think Mockery is used as mocking framework in Laravel tests. That link is perhaps missing in the answer now as you ask.

Comment: hmm interesting. So if I use mockery myself, what is the real added value of facades?

Comment: Facades in Laravel is quite a local term and I'm not so profound in Laravel that I could answer you that directly. But still, mocking works this way, use the real object not a test stub to assert your expectations. You perhaps (in your mental model) test/mock the "wrong" object. Think a bit out of the box, these are all tools to do something, use them according your needs.